# SQL: IN CONDITION

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

expression IN (value1 OR value2 OR  .... value_n)! ok

```
SELECT name
FROM orders
WHERE number IN (10000, 10001, 10003, 10005);
```

is

```
SELECT name
FROM orders
WHERE number = 10000
OR number = 10001
OR number = 10003
OR number = 10005;
```

how to do this?

expression IN (value1 AND value2 AND .... value_n)?

```
 SELECT name
    FROM orders
    WHERE number = 10000
    AND number = 10001
    AND number = 10003
    AND number = 10005;
```

[image]

havaleid and productid are foreign keys.

[image]

IN(62,63,61) is equal with IN(62,61) or ...

There aren't value of 63  in the table

query is : IN(62 OR 61 OR 63)

that's right?

my goal is : IN(62 AND 61 AND 63)

and for this query , nothing return ...

how to do ?

My english is little weak,sorry
Thanks

Comment: That query doesn't make sense.  In each row, `number` can only take on one of those values, so no rows will be returned.

Comment: how can one number simultaneously be equal to four different numbers? what are you really trying to do here?!

Comment: What is your question? It is not clear at all what you are trying to ask.

Comment: @RobP It's the Schrödinger's cat of SQL...

Comment: @ElGavilan so there may be rows that work, but once you run the query and look for them they are gone!

Comment: Instead of telling us what you're doing, tell us [what you want to achieve](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) since what you are doing makes no sense.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're looking for is all names that have all numbers assigned. Something like this:

```
SELECT name
    FROM orders
    WHERE number IN (10000, 10001, 10003, 10005)
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT number) = 4;
```

The `COUNT(DISTINCT...` ensures that every `name` returned has all four of those `number` values assigned.

Comment: This makes the most sense given the available information.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli Thanks a lot
 for your best answer